# Is there a better way to format these elements_by_id?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I have the following code I'm repeating and wondered if anyone had some advise as to how to write this more efficiently:

```
def get_description(links):
    for link in links:
        description = driver.find_elements_by_id('some-id')
        description = [x.text for x in description]
        description = " ".join(description)
        title = driver.find_elements_by_id('different-id')
        title = [x.text for x in title]
        title = " ".join(title)
        company = driver.find_elements_by_id('another-different-id')
        company = [x.text for x in company]
        company = " ".join(company)
        location = driver.find_elements_by_id('location-id')
        location = [x.text for x in location]
        location = " ".join(location)+ " United Kingdom"
        salary = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='randomly generated id']/div[3]/span[1]")
        salary = [x.text for x in salary]
        salary = " ".join(salary)
```

I tried defining a separate function called 'element_parse' as follows:

```
def parse_element(x)
    x = [y.text for y in x]
    x = " ".join(x)
```

then calling this the main function by doing:

```
description = driver.find_elements_by_id('some-id')
parse_element(description)
```

But alas! No joy.

Not a show stopper as I've got it working but feel like there's a lot of repetition in here I want to clean up!

Comment: If you want to improve working code, ask your question on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks Andersson - I wasn't aware of this. I'll have good use for CodeReview so appreciate you bringing this to my attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You need to return the value of x from your function, and reassign the value to that result. So:

```
def parse_element(x)
    x = [y.text for y in x]
    x = " ".join(x)
    return x
```

...

```
description = driver.find_elements_by_id('some-id')
description = parse_element(description)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! This definitely helped. I finished up by passing in another variable ('y') to the function which holds the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can shake off the repitition by trying something like below. Moreover, you don't need to create another function to clean things up.

```
def get_description(links):
    for link in links:
        description = ' '.join([x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_id('some-id')])
        title = ' '.join([x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_id('different-id')])
        company = ' '.join([x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_id('another-different-id')])
        location = ' '.join([x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_id('location-id')])
        salary = ' '.join([x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='randomly generated id']/div[3]/span[1]")])
```